# How to type-level assert a type is not any?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-assertion

I'm using a type-level `Assert` function to make assertions about the type-inferencing in my code. However, I'm not able to make any assertions about a type not being `any`.

```
type Assert<A extends ShouldBe, ShouldBe> = A

// @ts-expect-error
type SubsetObj = Assert<{ id: string }, { id: string; name: string }>
type SameObj = Assert<
    { id: string; name: string },
    { id: string; name: string }
>
type ExceedsObj = Assert<{ id: string; name: string }, { id: string }>

type SubsetUnion = Assert<number, number | string>
type SameUnion = Assert<number | string, number | string>

// @ts-expect-error
type ExceedUnion = Assert<number | string, number>

// @ts-expect-error  this is what I want to work.
type AnyShouldWork = Assert<any, number>
```

I've tried a few things with no avail. I noticed that `unknown` works as expected

```
// @ts-expect-error
type AssertUnknown = Assert<unknown, number>
```

And so I tried this code:

```
type IsAny<T> = unknown extends T ? (T extends {} ? T : never) : never
type NotAny<T> = T extends IsAny<T> ? unknown : T

type Assert2<A extends ShouldBe, ShouldBe> = Assert<NotAny<A>, ShouldBe>

// @ts-expect-error
type AssertAny = Assert2<any, number>
```

But this doesn't work because `Assert<NotAny<A>, ShouldBe>` fails right off the bat because `NotAny` can return unknown...

So I'm kind of stuck here... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better and much easier to use extra `Equals` helper:

```js
// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650
export type Equals<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;


type AssertTrue<A extends true> = A

// @ts-expect-error
type Test1 = AssertTrue<Equals<any, number>>
// @ts-expect-error
type Test2 = AssertTrue<Equals<unknown, number>>
// @ts-expect-error
type Test3 = AssertTrue<Equals<number | string, number>>
// @ts-expect-error
type Test4 = AssertTrue<Equals<{ id: string }, { id: string; name: string }>>
```

Comment: Interesting! Very odd that you cannot define `type Assert<A, B> = AssertTrue<Equals<A,B>>` and compose them together... Also, I would prefer if this wouldn't be a type error: `AssertTrue<Equals<number, number | string>>`. Thanks for the suggestion though, very helpful!

Comment: I have tried to do this without extra helper but without luck

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-expect with `TypeEqual` the package provides.

```
import { expectType, TypeEqual } from "ts-expect";
import { add } from "./adder";

expectType<number>(add(1, 2));
expectType<TypeEqual<number, ReturnType<typeof add>>>(true);
expectType<TypeEqual<[number, number], Parameters<typeof add>>>(true);
```